# Font-Awesome fonts are not loading after Spring'17 release

Tags: lightning-aura-components, static-resources

I am using Font-Awesome in my lightning components and using font-awesome icons in lightning components. It was working fine before 7th Jan 2017, but when today I Logged In into sandbox fonts are not working and showing error in console

> Access to Font at
>   'https://XXXX--XXXXX.cs26.my.salesforce.com/visualforce/sess…53669000%2FAll_Resources%2Ffonts%2Ffontawesome-webfont.woff%3Fv%3D4.2.0'
>   from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Is there any way to includes fonts directly in lightning components as we include CSS and JS files?

Comment: Make sure static resource accessibility is set to public.

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 thanks for prompt response, its already public.

Comment: May be there is a URL change. Try to whitelist the domain in CORS.

Comment: @SarojBera URL is same, and I also tried by adding into CORS but no luck.

Comment: Can you let us know where you changes the Font face. I mean in which file. Thanks,
Prdp

Comment: @pradeep As you can see in Answer I put the code sample that is the CSS file "font-awesome.css", where you will find fonts references.

Comment: Add applyBodyTag="false" and applyHtmlTag="false" in apex header.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution and changed the URL for the font files
from this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0');
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.2.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.2.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal
}
```

To this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('/resource/resource_name/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0');
    src: url'/resource/resource_name/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.2.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url(''/resource/resource_name/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0') format('woff'), url('/resource/resource_name/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0') format('truetype'), url('/resource/resource_name/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.2.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal
}
```