# Font Awesome fonts are not being loaded after "Enable Secure Static Resources" activated for testing

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, security, static-resources

Recently I have encountered the feature "Enable Secure Static Resources" on the release update (that was already being postponed as I am writing this) and read [this question talking about it](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/323985/what-is-the-impact-of-the-release-update-enable-secure-static-resources-for-li?noredirect=1#comment480211_323985) so I proceeded to test out if some of the built components we had are still functional.

I followed the mentioned steps on the release update to get it activated as *Test Run* then I went on checking the flexipages to verify if any error pops up in the chrome dev console concerning any of the resources included in the components.

This error shows up which is related to Font Awesome being included on the markup. I decided to re-create the scenario and narrowed down the problem to the code below.

[image]

```xml
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,force:LightningQuickAction">
    <ltng:require afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}"
        scripts="{!join(','
            ,$Resource.elfJquery_js
        )}"
        styles="{!join(','
            ,$Resource.elfFontAwesome5+'/css/all.css'
        )}"
    />
    
    <div id="hello">
        <i class="fas fa-address-card"></i>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

```js
({
    afterScriptsLoaded : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log($('#hello')); // jQuery is working properly under the feature
    }
})
```

I have come across [this solution](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155086/font-awesome-fonts-are-not-loading-after-spring17-release) and tried it by changing `all.css` then re-uploading it but it did not solve it. I have researched further but did not come across anything that seemed to fix it or a workaround it.

Comment: It looks same as the Known Issue : https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001JipTQAS

Comment: I enabled a test run for this release on my dev org and tested a simple aura component (_that uses a 3rd party JS file as static resource_). After enabling the test run, the resource was served from *Visualforce domain* and the aura component worked just fine. At the moment, I don't think there is a need to modify the code to load static resources in a different way. My guess is that the error you faced might not appear in all instances (_my org is on AP4_) and the release update has been postponed to to make is work on all instances.

Comment: I'm don't think namespacing would matter here, but it should be noted that the known issue (mentioned in the first comment) shows usage of namespaced resourceURL, while I tested one without namespace.